# Google Analytics metadata for column compatibility

Tags: google-analytics

Does anyone know if the Google Analytics API exposes the compatibility data for selecting a set of dimensions and measures?  For example, if I select the "ga:adGroup" dimension, then I can't select any of the Goal Completion dimensions.  This compatibility seems to be based upon the data cubes that are defined in Google.

Is this list of what dimensions and measures are compatible with each other programmatically available from the Google API?